# How to write GeoSPARQL query when hexadecimal representation of a binary encoded geometry

Tags: postgis, geometry, well-known-text, geosparql

I am trying to write a GeoSPARQL using the geometry column of a layer imported from QGIS to PostGIS. The format of the geometry column is hexadecimal representation of a binary. When I try to use `geo:aswkt` it doesn't work and return empty results.

```
?geometry geo:asWKT ?wkt_representation .
```

Comment: You're converting on the wrong side. `ST_AsText()` belongs in the SQL statement.

Comment: if i converted using ST_AsText() in SQL , would i be able to use GeoSPARQL functions like geof:sfWithin?

Comment: That's a question for GeoSPARQL documentation, surely. If you need WKT input, you need to generate it before input.